# How to convert Arithmetic and binary operation to their respected symbols & values

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I'm getting JSON values from the backend. I'm facing the problem in conversion of values. I'm getting the value as `greaterThan` and I should display it as `>`  and I'm getting status as `1` and i need to display it as `on` in my frontend. How can I achieve that?
Below are my JSON values

```
{fact: "s1", operator: "greaterThan", value: 8, status: "on", $$hashKey: "object:52"}
```

the required output should be converted into this format

```
{fact: "s1", operator:">", value: 8, status: 1, $$hashKey: "object:52"}
```

Comment: can you add input json and expected output.

Comment: @RahulSharma please have a look. Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.json = [{
  "fact": "s1",
  "operator": "greaterThan",
  "value": 8,
  "status": "on",
  "$$hashKey": "object:52"
}];

angular.forEach($scope.json, function(value, key) {
    if (value.operator == "greaterThan")
        value.operator = '>';

    if (value.status == 1)
        value.operator = 'on';

    return value;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
var data = [{
  fact: "s1",
  operator: "greaterThan",
  value: 8,
  status: "on",
  $$hashKey: "object:52"
}];

data = data.map((val) => {
  if (val.operator == "greaterThan")
    val.operator = '>';
  if (val.status == 1)
    val.operator = 'on';
  return val;
});

console.log(data);
```